# newsletter blast out script fail to blast out letter

Tags: php, mysql

every time i'm simply try to run this script i keep getting these error messages

> (Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /home/a9016774/public_html/cronjob/blast_script.php
>   on line 9)

and

> (Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not
>   a valid MySQL result resource in
>   /home/a9016774/public_html/cronjob/blast_script.php on line 21).

here is the code:

```
<?php
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
Script written by Adam Khoury @ www.developphp.com
                          January 1, 2010
Please retain this credit when displaying this code online 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
include_once "../connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE received='0' LIMIT 20");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql); // Added for "End Campaign Check" at the bottom of this file(not shown on the video)
$mail_body = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $name = $row["name"];

    $mail_body = '<html>
<body style="background-color:#CCC; color:#000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em;">
<h3><a href="http://newsletter.netau.net/"><img src="http://www.yoursite.com/images/logo.png" alt="DevelopPHP" width="216" height="36" border="0"></a> Newsletter
</h3>
<p>Hello ' . $name . ',</p>
<p>You can make this out to be just like most any web page or design format you require using HTML and CSS.</p>
<p>~Adam @ DevelopPHP</p>
<hr>
<p>To opt out of receiving this newsletter,  <a href="http://newsletter.netau.net/optout.php?e=' . $email . '">click here</a> and we will remove you from the listing immediately.</p>
</body>
</html>';
    $subject = "Develop PHP Newsletter";
    $headers  = "From:newsletter@newsletter.netau.net\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $to = "$email";

    $mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);

    if ($mail_result) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET received='1' WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
    } else {
       // this else statement can be used to write into an error log if the mail function fails
       // It can also be removed if you do not need error logging
    }

}
?>
<?php
// This section is script I discussed adding to this file on video
// This section is for sending the site owner a message informing them that
// all people in the database have been sent the newsletter for the current campaign
if ($numRows == 0) { // $numRows is set on line 4 using the existing query

     $subj = "Newsletter Campaign Has Ended";
     $body = "The current newsletter campaign has ended. All have been sent the newsletter.";
     $hdr  = "From:newsletter@newsletter.netau.net\r\n";
     $hdr .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
     mail("austinbevon79@gmail.com", $subj, $body, $hdr);

}
// End Check Section
?>
```

please help and thank you!

Comment: Could you be having the same problem as in [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202)?

Comment: *blast out*?? most of us just end email

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns `False` when error happens during execution of SQL. And `False` is not a mysql resource expected by functions `mysql_num_rows` and `mysql_fetch_array`, and this is what happens here. You probably don't have necessary table `newsletter` or the table is missing column `received`.

You can check what the error is by adding

```
echo mysql_error($sql);
```

after this line:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE received='0' LIMIT 20");
```